# Input ( ) problems

Tags: python-3.x

The code I have is:

```
print("you slowly open your eyes and look around.\n")
print
print("The room you are in has a chest of drawers in the corner, a nightstand, and a loose floorboard.\n")
print
place = input ('What do you examine first: ' )
print("you inspect the place. Underneath you find a small stick.")
```

Unfortunately, when I test it, the last print sequence says:

> you inspect the place. Underneath you find a small stick

Instead of saying:

> you inspect the floorboard/cabinet/nightstand. Underneath you find a small stick.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The "place" in your last line is just a string, not the variable you got before, you need to inject the variable to the whole string.

Something like follows:

```
place = input ('What do you examine first: ' )
print("you inspect the %s. Underneath you find a small stick." % place)
```

More methods to do it, reference to [this](https://matthew-brett.github.io/teaching/string_formatting.html).

Comment: `%` is a really old syntax. Consider switching to `"you inspect the {}. ...".format(place)` or `f"you inspect the {place}..."`.

Answer (score 0):

USe this and its gonna work

```
print(f"you inspect the {place}. Underneath you find a small stick.")
```

Comment: thanks. I have read the basics and im pretty skilled in python, but its been years sine I last used it, and a few things have changed.